# Is it possible to extend Three.JS Mesh using classes?

Tags: javascript, three.js

As i understand it ECMAscript 6 class syntax is just syntactical sugar for the prototypical pattern of inheritance used prior, however I am confused about how to extend the Three.js Mesh object to use with the class syntax.

At the moment I have a working 'class' based on the prototypical pattern:

```
function GFAElement(params) {
    //
    var p = params.split("-");
    var userData = {
        type:    "GFA",
        flights: parseInt(p[0]),
        pitch:   parseInt(p[1]),
        length:  parseInt(p[2])
    };

    var shape = getProfile();

    var extrudeSettings = {
        steps: 5*userData.length,
        depth: userData.length,
        bevelEnabled: false
    };

    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
        color: 0xffffff,
        metalness: 0.5,
        roughness: 0.5,
    } );

    THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );

    this.geometry.vertices.forEach( vertex => {
        var angle = 2*Math.PI/userData.flights*vertex.z/userData.pitch;
        var updateX = vertex.x * Math.cos(angle) - vertex.y * Math.sin(angle);
        var updateY = vertex.y * Math.cos(angle) + vertex.x * Math.sin(angle);
        vertex.x = updateX;
        vertex.y = updateY;
    });
    this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    this.type = 'GFAElement';
    this.userData = userData;

}

GFAElement.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
GFAElement.prototype.constructor = GFAElement;
```

I have made an attempt to convert this into the class syntax:

```
class GFAElement extends THREE.Mesh {

    constructor(params){
        super();

        this.type = 'GFAElement';

        var p = params.split("-");
        this.userData.type = "GFA",
        this.userData.flights = parseInt(p[0]);
        this.userData.pitch   = parseInt(p[1]);
        this.userData.length  = parseInt(p[2]);

        this.generate();

    }

    generate(){

        var shape = getProfile();

        var extrudeSettings = {
            steps: 5*this.userData.length,
            depth: this.userData.length,
            bevelEnabled: false
        };

        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
        var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
            color: 0xffffff,
            metalness: 0.5,
            roughness: 0.5,
        } );

        THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );

        this.geometry.vertices.forEach( vertex => {
            var angle = 2*Math.PI/this.userData.flights*vertex.z/this.userData.pitch;
            var updateX = vertex.x * Math.cos(angle) - vertex.y * Math.sin(angle);
            var updateY = vertex.y * Math.cos(angle) + vertex.x * Math.sin(angle);
            vertex.x = updateX;
            vertex.y = updateY;
        });
        this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    }

}
```

This however gives me an error:

```
three.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: id
```

which i think is the result of an incompatible `extends THREE.Mesh` and `THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );`, however i have not been able to correct this incompatibility.

This leaves me to my main question, how do i convert the above presented prototypical pattern into the class syntax?

```js
'use strict';

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var screw, mirror;

// Screw parameters
var P = 2; // number of flights

var D = 50, // outer diameter
  Dr = D/1.66, // root diameter
  Cl = (Dr+D)/2, // centerline distance
  αi = 2*Math.acos(Cl/D),
  Ih = D*Math.sin(αi/2)/2,
  H = D-Cl;

var αf = αi,
  αt = Math.PI/P - αf,
  αr = αt;

//console.log(D, Dr, Cl, Ih, H);
//console.log(αi, αf, αt, αr);

function getFlankParams(α1, D1, α2, D2, ctr){
 // flanks are arcs with origin (xc, yc) of radius Cl passing through (x1, y1) and (x2, y2):
 // (x1-xc)^2 + (y1-yc)^2 = Cl^2
 // (x2-xc)^2 + (y2-yc)^2 = Cl^2
 var x1 = D1*Math.cos(α1),
   y1 = D1*Math.sin(α1),
   x2 = D2*Math.cos(α2),
   y2 = D2*Math.sin(α2);
 // Solving system of equations yields linear eq:
 // y1-yc = beta - alpha*(x1-xc)
 var alpha = (x1-x2)/(y1-y2), 
   beta = (y1-y2)*(1+Math.pow(alpha,2))/2;
 // Substitution and applying quadratic equation:
 var xc = x1 - alpha*beta/(1+Math.pow(alpha,2))*(1+Math.pow(-1,ctr)*Math.sqrt(1-(1-Math.pow(Cl/beta,2))*(1+1/Math.pow(alpha,2)))),
   yc = y1 + alpha*(x1-xc) - beta;
 // Following from law of consines, the angle the flank extends wrt its own origin:
 var asq = Math.pow(Dr/2,2)+Math.pow(D/2,2)-2*(Dr/2)*(D/2)*Math.cos(αf),
   af = Math.acos(1-asq/Math.pow(Cl, 2)/2);

 var params = {xc: xc, yc: yc, af: af};
 return params;
}

function getProfile() {

 var shape = new THREE.Shape();
 var angle = 0, ctr = 0;
 // loop over number of flights
 for (var p=0; p<P; p++){
  // tip
  shape.absarc(0, 0, D/2, angle, angle+αt);
  angle += αt; 
  // flank
  var params = getFlankParams(angle, D/2, angle+αf, Dr/2, ctr++);
  shape.absarc(params.xc, params.yc, Cl, angle+αf-params.af, angle+αf, false);
  angle += αf; 
  // root
  shape.absarc(0, 0, Dr/2, angle, angle+αr);
  angle += αr; 
  // flank
  params = getFlankParams(angle, Dr/2, angle+αf, D/2, ctr++);
  shape.absarc(params.xc, params.yc, Cl, angle, angle+αf-params.af, false);
  angle += αf;
 }
 return shape;

}

function GFAElement(params) {
 //
 var p = params.split("-");
 var userData = {
  type:   "GFA",
  flights: parseInt(p[0]),
  pitch:   parseInt(p[1]),
  length:  parseInt(p[2])
 };

 var shape = getProfile();

 var extrudeSettings = {
  steps: 5*userData.length,
  depth: userData.length,
  bevelEnabled: false
 };

 var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
 var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
  color: 0xffffff,
  metalness: 0.5,
  roughness: 0.5,
 } );

 THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );

 this.geometry.vertices.forEach( vertex => {
  var angle = 2*Math.PI/userData.flights*vertex.z/userData.pitch;
  var updateX = vertex.x * Math.cos(angle) - vertex.y * Math.sin(angle);
  var updateY = vertex.y * Math.cos(angle) + vertex.x * Math.sin(angle);
  vertex.x = updateX;
  vertex.y = updateY;
 });
 this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
 this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

 this.type = 'GFAElement';
 this.userData = userData;
  
}

GFAElement.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Mesh.prototype );
GFAElement.prototype.constructor = GFAElement;
//GFAElement.prototype.getMesh = function() {return this.mesh;}

class NewGFAElement extends THREE.Mesh {

 constructor(params){
  super();
  
  this.type = 'GFAElement';
  
  var p = params.split("-");
  this.userData.type = "GFA",
  this.userData.flights = parseInt(p[0]);
  this.userData.pitch   = parseInt(p[1]);
  this.userData.length  = parseInt(p[2]);
  
  this.generate();
  
 }

 generate(){
 
  var shape = getProfile();

  var extrudeSettings = {
   steps: 5*this.userData.length,
   depth: this.userData.length,
   bevelEnabled: false
  };

  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
  var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
   color: 0xffffff,
   metalness: 0.5,
   roughness: 0.5,
  } );

  THREE.Mesh.call( this, geometry, material );
  
  this.geometry.vertices.forEach( vertex => {
   var angle = 2*Math.PI/this.userData.flights*vertex.z/this.userData.pitch;
   var updateX = vertex.x * Math.cos(angle) - vertex.y * Math.sin(angle);
   var updateY = vertex.y * Math.cos(angle) + vertex.x * Math.sin(angle);
   vertex.x = updateX;
   vertex.y = updateY;
  });
  this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  
 }

}

class KBElement extends THREE.Group {
 //
 constructor(params){
  super();
   
  this.type = 'KBElement';

  var p = params.split("-");
  this.userData.type = "KB";
  this.userData.thickness = parseInt(p[0]);
  this.userData.flights   = parseInt(p[1]);
  this.userData.length    = parseInt(p[2]);
  this.userData.stagAngle = parseInt(p[3]);

  this.generate();
 }
 
 generate(){
 
  var shape = getProfile();

  var extrudeSettings = {
   depth: this.userData.thickness,
   bevelEnabled: false
  };

  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
  var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
   color: 0xffffff,
   metalness: 0.5,
   roughness: 0.5,
  } );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

  super.add( mesh );
  for (var n=1, nt = this.userData.length/this.userData.thickness; n<nt; n++){
   mesh = mesh.clone();
   mesh.position.z += this.userData.thickness;
   mesh.rotation.z += this.userData.stagAngle;
   super.add( mesh );
  }
  
 }
 
}

class Screw extends THREE.Group {
 //
 constructor(){
  super();
 }

 add(desc){
  var elem;
  var params = desc.split(" ");
  if (params[0] == "GFA") {
   elem = new NewGFAElement(params[1]);
  } else
  if (params[0] == "KB") {
   elem = new KBElement(params[1]);
  }
  super.add(elem);
 }

}

function init() {
 
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 //renderer.gammaInput = true;
 //renderer.gammaOutput = true;
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
 
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x222222 );

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
 camera.position.set( 200, 200, 200 );
  scene.add( camera );
 
 var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
 camera.add( light );
 
 controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
 controls.minDistance = 100;
 controls.maxDistance = 500;

 screw = new Screw();
 screw.add('GFA 2-40-90');
 //screw.add('KB 5-2-30-90');
 
 //var mirror = screw.mirror();
 //scene.add(screw, mirror);
  scene.add(screw);
 
 console.log(screw);
 
}

function animate() {
 
 //group.rotation.z  -= 2*Math.PI/100;
 //mirror.rotation.z -= 2*Math.PI/100;

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 controls.update();
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
   body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
   a {
    color: #f80;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure that `super()` is called before accessing the `this` reference in `GFAElement`'s constructor. So create the geometry and material first and then call `super` like this:

```
super( geometry, material );
```

The following fiddle shows the approach in a complete example based on your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/12523/

Comment: ok understood, thx! sideways related: Do you know how i can clone an instance of `GFAElement`? I tried using `clone()` but it failed with `Uncaught TypeError: params.split is not a function`

Comment: I guess you have to overwrite `.clone()` in your class similar how `Mesh.clone()` works.